# what's the difference between -funwind-tables and -fasynchronous-unwind-tables?

Tags: gcc, android-ndk, clang, llvm

I've searched for a while about what's the difference between `-funwind-tables` and `-fasynchronous-unwind-tables`, but it seems there was not an exactly answer which could give a clear explanation.

In other worlds :

What's the difference between asynchronous-unwind-tables and unwind-tables?

What's the meaning and advantages of **asynchronous**?

Thanks.

Some related materials I've found:

[3.17 Options for Code Generation Conventions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-funwind-tables-1203)

[[llvm-dev] [RFC] Asynchronous unwind tables attribute](https://groups.google.com/g/llvm-dev/c/KH4QAKPBQ5A)

[[git commit] libubacktrace: use -funwind-tables rather than -fexecptions](https://lists.uclibc.org/pipermail/uclibc/2012-January/046182.html)